# How to trigger CKEditor's widget upcast function after DOM rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I initialize CKEditor in a React component like this:

```
render: () ->
  <div ref="editable" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: @props.html}} />

componentDidMount: () ->
  @editor = AlloyEditor.editable(@refs.editable, {extraPlugins: AlloyEditor.Core.ATTRS.extraPlugins.value + 'plugins go here'})
  @editor.get('nativeEditor').on('blur', (event) =>
    @props.handleChange())
  //At this point the @props.html changes and the component is re-rendered
```

I define widgets following this [tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1). The appropriate html elements are properly recognized as widgets and everything works fine until the 'blur' event is fired. After the component is re-rendered, the widgets' upcast functions don't get invoked again and the html elements don't become widgets any longer.

I thought that I could use methods such as `checkWidgets` and `initOnAll` in the `componentDidUpdate` method, but they only work for widget candidates with `.cke_widget_new` class. As far as I understand, the upcasting happens at the data (html) processing stage, and it looks like the editor doesn't process html again after DOM was re-rendered. What can I do about this? Thanks!

**Update:** Eventually oleq's solution worked for me. I added:

```
componentDidUpdate: () ->
  data = @editor.get('nativeEditor').getData()
  @editor.get('nativeEditor').setData(data)
```

The only problem is that this (and probably any other) solution doesn't work with the `blur` event, which was a bad event choice, because it is also triggered right before the user adds a widget by pressing a button. I replaced this event with another one that seems to work for me at least for now.

Comment: I'm not a react guy but as far as I understand it collects raw editor HTML `editor.editable().getHtml()` (which is not data!) and then, after re–initialisation, it simply puts it back, but all the internal editor references to the elements (also widgets) are broken because it's basically a new tree. Could you somehow configure React so it uses `editor.getData()` to collect HTML, and then `editor.setData( data )` to re–render it? Then all widgets would initialise automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This almost works.  The only problem is that now widgets get inserted at the very top of the editable element (and inserting a second widget throws an error). I will try to figure out why this is happening. The `data` returned by `editor.getData()` already has the future widget above the rest of html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use editor.widgets.checkWidgets() as documented here:

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_plugins_widget_repository.html

The general idea is that it checks all the widgets in the document and refreshes ones that have not been made widgets yet.

OR if you only want to init one widget that you have a reference to, do it with initOn() documented on the same page.